# Using PrinceXML in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, princexml

I'm trying to use PrinceXML in my project to generate a PDF to document, I tried to make a simple PDF file with it but does not appear to create a PDF file. So I did a little bit of debugging and tried to run the exe of PrinceXML.

```
public function executePrincePDF(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $output = system("D:\\Program Files\\xampp\\htdocs\\leave\\lib\\vendor\\prince\\Engine\\bin\prince.exe --version");
  echo $output;

  return sfView::NONE;
}
```

But there is no output, I've seen the expected output because I tried running the code above with a plain php file and the output is this:

`Prince 8.1 rev 4 Copyright 2002-2012 YesLogic Pty. Ltd. Non-commercial License Non-commercial License`

How do I use PrinceXML in Symfony 1.4? Is there something I need to do before I use PrinceXML?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the provided php wrapper class. http://www.princexml.com/download/wrappers/

Rename it to `Prince.class.php` and put it into the `lib` directory so symfony will autoload it and read the readme file to see how can you use it.